# how do I achieve a rotational "spring back" effect in SceneKit?

Tags: scenekit

I am trying to achieve the effect of the wooden rod in this animation, using SceneKit:

https://www.instagram.com/p/BkzqpHHgKb1/

The rod can spin around it's center, and then snaps back to it's original position.

I have an elongated Scenekit SCNBox representing the rod. I'm using SCNPhysicsHingeJoint on the rod's physics body to give it the ability to rotate around it's center:

```
 let joint = SCNPhysicsHingeJoint(body: (rod.physicsBody!), axis:SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 1) , anchor: SCNVector3(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 0))
 scnView.scene?.physicsWorld.addBehavior(joint)
```

Is there a way to make the rod spring back into it's original position by manipulating the physics properties such as restitution, angularDamping, etc? Can I achieve this with an SCNPhysicsField.spring() ?

Or, do I just manually animate the rod back to it's original position?

I've set up a lot of this in the SceneKit editor so there's not a lot of code, but I could rewrite as code if that is useful for this question.